# Is a self referential one-to-many Core Data relationship possible?

Tags: swift, objective-c, join, core-data

I’m learning to use Core Data and I have some ideas for modeling data. As someone trying to learn German, I’m making a log book of phrases and some context around them like the text’s language, a note, and possible translations.

### First Idea

Here’s a very simplified model:

```swift
class Phrase: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var text: String
  @NSManaged var language: String
  @NSManaged var translations: Set<Phrase>
  @NSManaged var note: String?
}
```

The `translations` property would be a one-to-many relationship. Is this even possible given how Core Data stores data?

### Second Idea

In my research it sounds like I might need an intermediate object to facilitate a join table. Something more like this:

```swift
class Phrase: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var text: String
  @NSManaged var language: String
  @NSManaged var translations: Set<Translation> // one-to-many: Translation.input
  @NSManaged var note: String?
}

class Translation: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var input: Phrase // one-to-many: Phrase.translations
  @NSManaged var text: String
  @NSManaged var language: String
  @NSManaged var note: String?
}
```

#### Conclusion

I feel like I might be thinking of the problem incorrectly. Is there a better model for this structure?

Comment: Yes an entity in Core Data can have a relationship to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of those will work but it's important to be aware of how Core Data differs from a relational database. In both cases Core Data will complain that there's no inverse relationship. It expects to have a property for the relationship on both ends. In the first case it will expect a second relationship that you might call `translatedFrom` or something. You don't ever need to use that relationship, but it's good to have it for Core Data's internal use.

Aside from that you can go with either approach. The second has the possible advantage that you can add notes or other data specifically about the translation, separately from each phrase. If you don't need that though, don't bother with a second entity.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. For my first idea I will try to add a `translationOf` property but I’m not sure if this should be a `Set<Phrase>` or just a `Phrase?`. I feel like both should be possible but because phrases can be translated into multiple languages it’s better as a many-to-many relationship. Am I on the right track?

Comment: It depends whether the relationship is many-to-one or many-to-many. That’s your call based on how you think you’ll use the data.